# Text inside TextView is changing when putting error message

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView in my Android application showing a text :

TextView before Error message

[image: image1]

when some action occurs , I put an error message to this TextView :

TextView after an Error message

[image: image2]

my problem is the text position won't be the same as you see in both pic

What can i do to solve this problem ?

ــــــــ

Update : 
Xml code for pic above

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayOut"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: the alignment (for TextView its called "gravity") in both cases is "left". You could change them to center, right and etc.

Comment: Can you please share your code here.

Comment: Provide [MCVE]..

Comment: You want alignment to be same in both the pics?

Comment: @Taier it didn't work , the text position still changing

Comment: @Jay the code is very simply , just i have a even for buttons :
if they clicked and the question not answered the error message will be shown

Comment: @UmangBurman exactly :)

Comment: @AliAl-Hudhud Ah, position, you wrote alignment in the question. In order for a text to be the same, change the visibility of your error message icon from gone to invisible in order to hide it.

Comment: This is depended from your layout gravity, by default gravity is left. You can change this to the center with view width to `match_parent`, it's esty way to display text more/less aligned. Android by default doesn't support justyfication, but you can achieve this using github libraries.

Comment: @AliAl-Hudhud If the view is coming there then obviously there will be a text adjustment there, no matter what gravity you give.

Comment: @AliAl-Hudhud Share your xml code, we'll help you solve it.

Comment: @UmangBurman done , i updated the question

Comment: @Taier by overriding the setError method ?

Comment: @AliAl-Hudhud depends on your code, I can't see it. Search for "gone" word in your method that sets the visibility of error and change it to "invisible"

Comment: @AliAl-Hudhud What is the requirement of the app so that you are making the setError thingy.. Why you want to set error there?

Answer (score 1):

Try having definite predefined space for the error drawable and have their layout wight specified.

Answer (score 0):

The alignment in both cases is left. Just it looks disturbed because after error message, textview adjust space of error icon also. To manage space for error icon(red) textview manage text in available space after showing error message.

Hope this solves the problem.
If no then share your code will make easy to solve problem.

Comment: sorry I meant text position , just updated the quesion

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the alignment for textview to center and alignment to error message to right by changing component properties.

Answer (score 0):

Well with `TextView` the error `Drawable` is covering space this is why `Text` is redrawn in remaining area.

To disable this behavior The only way i can think of right now is to make use of :
`setError(CharSequence error, Drawable icon)`.

`setError` will set the right drawable whenever you call it . So the idea is initially use a same size of transparent icon as a `drawableRight` for  `TextView`.

And whenever you reset Error set the same transparent drawable again .

```
   textView.setError(null);
   textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.transparent_drawable, 0);
```